# What's the type of keys of a dictionary of dictionaries in the form of a plist?

Tags: swift4, xcode9.2

Xcode 9.2 ;
Swift 4

I manually made a dictionary in the form of a plist. It is a dictionary of dictionaries as is shown in the next image:

[image: The property list in question]

Now I want to get the info from the plist, so I try to decode it. However, I'm forced to give the types of the elements involved. So, the question is, what´s the form of the dictionary described by this plist? (For example: an array of Strings would be written as [String]).
Thanks in advance.

Update: This is the code I'm using, and the result when I try [String:[String:Int]].

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The root dictionary is `[String:Any]` or more specific `[String[String:Int]]` considering only the **visible** sub-dictionary.

If the other dictionaries contain different types than `[String:Int]` you cannot use `PropertyListDecoder()` without writing a custom initializer.

**Update:**

This is a q&d example which serializes a dictionary to property list the usual way and decode it with `PropertyListDecoder()`.

Try it in a playground

```
let dict = ["diccioNum": ["Num3": 3, "Num4": 4, "Num6": 6, "Num8": 8, "Num9": 9, "Num5": 5, "Num1": 1, "Num7": 7, "Num2": 2]]
do {
    let plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: dict, format: .xml, options: 0)

    let plist = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([String: [String:Int]].self, from: plistData)
    print(plist)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I updated the post with the code in a playground.

Comment: You didn't mention that you are going to use `PropertyListDecoder`. What kind of result do you expect? If you want to decode the property list into structs you have to declare a property for each key of the inner dictionaries. And please post code, not screenshots.

Comment: The other subdictionaries are equal as the visible, except that NUM is replaced by ALG,GEO and DYA. Is there a way to know the type of the keys, or I have to create the plist with code as you did in the example?